# IdentityServer3 with aspnet core client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have setup IdentityServer3 and can successfully authenticate using a username and password stored on an aspnetIdentity database. The problem is on the client MVC application side. After receiving the authorization code from identityserver application it then throws the following exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to
>   handle the scheme: cookies

My `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
app.UseStaticFiles();
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true

});
var secret = Configuration["Secrets:SharedSecret"];//.ToSha256();
var connectOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    AutomaticAuthenticate=true,
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "cookies",
    Authority = "http://localhost:4889/core/",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5059/",
    CallbackPath = "/home/index",
    ClientSecret = secret,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ClientId = "communicator",
    DisplayName = "Communicator",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
    SaveTokens = true,
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnUserInformationReceived = async y =>
        {

            var identity = y.Ticket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var subject = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Type == "sub");
            // Do something with subject like lookup in local users DB.
            var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity( y.Ticket.AuthenticationScheme,"given_name","role");
            // Do some stuff to `newIdentity` like adding claims.
            // Create a new ticket with `newIdentity`.
                //Ticket = new Ticket(new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity),
                //y.Ticket.Properties,
                //y.Ticket.AuthenticationScheme);

            await Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived= async c=>
        {
            var identity = c.Ticket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var subject =   identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Type == "sub");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }

    }
};
connectOptions.Scope.Clear();
connectOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
connectOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
connectOptions.Scope.Add("roles");
connectOptions.Scope.Add("smsapi");
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(connectOptions);
```

Comment: Is `AuthenticationScheme` case sensitive in `CookieAuthenticationOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a case-sensitivity issue in your configuration.